# How can I select specific instances of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on improving my client reporting for fundraising performance, and I put in specific reference codes to be able to track email performance. I've successfully loaded in my data frame, but I don't know how to select specific instances of a column.

For example, I'm trying to graph performance of 3 reference codes (SAN_20210811_GEN_FDR_X, SAN_20210808_GEN_ENG_X, and SAN_20210803_GEN_FDR_X). I loaded in my data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Sandro\Downloads\SANdata.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Amount','Reference Code'].
print (df)
```

Is there a way to filter the specific instances of my reference codes to then get a sum for each?

I'm thinking something like:

```
df.loc[df['Reference Code'] == "SAN_20210811_GEN_FDR_X"]
```

But I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: `df.groupby("Reference Code")["Amount"].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a specific reference code:

```
df['Amount'].loc[df['Reference Code'] == "SAN_20210811_GEN_FDR_X"].sum()
```

For all reference codes:

```
df.groupby('Reference Code')['Amount'].sum()
```

Comment: This worked immediately. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer because it worked for you.